# How to broadcast scipy.linalg.eigvals for two matrix a(20,20) and b(100,20,20)?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, eigenvalue

I am trying to apply scipy.linalg.eigvals(a,b) for two matrix a(2, 2) and b(3, 2, 2) i.e., broadcasting for 100 b_i(20,20) matrices.

Here is an example code

```py
# Import scipy.linalg module
import scipy.linalg as la

# Define a(2,2) matrix
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

# Define b(3,2,2) array of matrices
b = [[[5, 6], [7, 8]], [[9, 10], [11, 12]], [[13, 14], [15, 16]]]

# Compute the eigenvalues of a and b using scipy.linalg.eigvals
eigvals = la.eigvals(a,b)

# Print the eigenvalues
print(eigvals)
```

but I am getting following error.

```py
  File ~\miniconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_decomp.py:896 in eigvals
    return eig(a, b=b, left=0, right=0, overwrite_a=overwrite_a,

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\py311\Lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_decomp.py:222 in eig
    raise ValueError('expected square matrix')

ValueError: expected square matrix
```

Can any provide an option to broadcast the scipy.linalg.eigvals to these a, b matrices?

Comment: `eigvals` says both `a` and `b` have to be (m,m), square arrays.  `np.linalg.eigvals` takes a `a` with shape ` (..., M, M)`, but doesn't have the `b` argument.

Comment: The error is produced in a block early in `eig` that reads: `if len(b1.shape) != 2 or b1.shape[0] != b1.shape[1]:  raise ValueError('expected square matrix')`.  Clearly `b` has to be 2d square.  There's no "vectorized/broadcasted" way around that.

Comment: Not sure if completely valid or if efficient, but you may be able to use numpy: `eigvals = np.linalg.eigvals(np.linalg.inv(b) @ a)`

Comment: From Wikipedia: """If B is invertible, then the original problem can be written in the form B^-1 A v =\lambda v, which is a standard eigenvalue problem. However, in most situations it is preferable not to perform the inversion, but rather to solve the generalized eigenvalue problem as stated originally.""" But I don't know enough about the linear algebra to determine if this is problematic in your case

Comment: As @Chrysophylaxs mentioned, I am currently using `np.linalg.eigvals(np.linalg.inv(b) @ a)` for in my code. But I am looking for a solution where I don't have to inverse `b`.

Comment: If given a valid `b`, the `scipy` `eig`, calls `_geneig(a1, b1, left, right, overwrite_a, overwrite_b,...)`  I assume `_geneig` is the compiled library `generalize eigen value` function.  Keeping in mind that a "few" loops of a complex operation are often as good as one fully-vectorized-solution, calling `eig` 100 time might not be a bad option.

Comment: In my case, the b matrix can be a multi dimension matrix (12, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 2). For that writing for loop for each dimension can be clunky.

Comment: That `b` can be reshaped to 3d.

Comment: That is true. I can try that.